# PHP new line character not working

Tags: php

I want to print a new line character in browser but '\n' in echo statement does nothing. Whats wrong in this code?

```
$n = 5;
for($i= 0; $i<=$n; $i++)
{
for($j=0; $j <= $n-$i-1; $j++)
echo "&nbsp;";
for( ; $j <= $n; $j++)
echo '* ';
echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: just `echo '<br/>';`

Comment: I used this as an alternative. but I want to know the reason why this not workin

Comment: look to source of html page. You will see your \n :) they are spaces in html

Comment: \n work this way  <?php
echo nl2br("One line.\nAnother line.");
?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually working, if you see your html source you will find it, whereas HTML needs `<br>` instead of new line character. if you want to convert new line to `<br>` you can use php function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

```
echo nl2br($stingHasNewLineChar);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `"echo"` command in PHP sends the output to the browser as raw html so even if in double quotes the browser will not parse it into two lines because a newline character in HTML means nothing. That's why you need to either use:

```
echo [output text]."<br>";
when using "echo", or instead use fwrite...

fwrite([output text]."\n");
This will output HTML newline in place of "\n".
```